# how to add custom speech in botframe work

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on Custom speech in bot framework.I add Bing simple speech it is working on my website: here is link :https://envolvebot.azurewebsites.net/

but now i want to know how can we add custom speech (LUIS custom speech) in our webchat bot?
I create custom speech using : https://westus.cris.ai/Home/CustomSpeech
Now i want to add it and want it to work like bing speech .

i am using following code.

```
 /*! modernizr 3.6.0 (Custom Build) | MIT *
    * https://modernizr.com/download/?-getusermedia-speechsynthesis !*/
    !function (e, n, s) { function i(e, n) { return typeof e === n } function o() { var e, n, s, o, a, f, d; for (var c in t) if (t.hasOwnProperty(c)) { if (e = [], n = t[c], n.name && (e.push(n.name.toLowerCase()), n.options && n.options.aliases && n.options.aliases.length)) for (s = 0; s < n.options.aliases.length; s++)e.push(n.options.aliases[s].toLowerCase()); for (o = i(n.fn, "function") ? n.fn() : n.fn, a = 0; a < e.length; a++)f = e[a], d = f.split("."), 1 === d.length ? Modernizr[d[0]] = o : (!Modernizr[d[0]] || Modernizr[d[0]] instanceof Boolean || (Modernizr[d[0]] = new Boolean(Modernizr[d[0]])), Modernizr[d[0]][d[1]] = o), r.push((o ? "" : "no-") + d.join("-")) } } var t = [], a = { _version: "3.6.0", _config: { classPrefix: "", enableClasses: !0, enableJSClass: !0, usePrefixes: !0 }, _q: [], on: function (e, n) { var s = this; setTimeout(function () { n(s[e]) }, 0) }, addTest: function (e, n, s) { t.push({ name: e, fn: n, options: s }) }, addAsyncTest: function (e) { t.push({ name: null, fn: e          }) } }, Modernizr = function () { }; Modernizr.prototype = a, Modernizr = new Modernizr, Modernizr.addTest("speechsynthesis", "SpeechSynthesisUtterance" in e), Modernizr.addTest("getUserMedia", "mediaDevices" in navigator && "getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices); var r = []; o(), delete a.addTest, delete a.addAsyncTest; for (var f = 0; f < Modernizr._q.length; f++)Modernizr._q[f](); e.Modernizr = Modernizr }(window, document);

    // Necessary for safari
    // Safari will only speak after speaking from a button click
    var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
    debugger;
    function SpeakText() {
        var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

        document.getElementsByClassName("wc-mic")[0].removeEventListener("click", SpeakText);
    }

    if (isSafari) {

        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            document.getElementsByClassName("wc-mic")[0].addEventListener("click", SpeakText);
        });
    }

    var femaleVoice = null;

    if (Modernizr.speechsynthesis) {
        var baseSpeechPrototype = SpeechSynthesisUtterance.prototype;
        SpeechSynthesisUtterance = function (msg) {
            var utterance = new baseSpeechPrototype.constructor(msg);

            if (femaleVoice != null)
                utterance.voice = femaleVoice;

            return utterance;
        }

        window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function () {
            var voice = "Microsoft Zira";
            var safariVoice = "Samantha";

            var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            voices.forEach(function (v) {
                if (v.name.startsWith(voice))
                    femaleVoice = v;
                else if (v.name == safariVoice && v.lang == "en-US")
                    femaleVoice = v;
            })
        }
    }

    //// Needed to change between the two audio contexts
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    //// Sets the old style getUserMedia to use the new style that is supported in more browsers even though the framework uses the new style
    if (window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia && !window.navigator.getUserMedia) {
        window.navigator.getUserMedia = function (constraints, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(function (e) {
                    successCallback(e);
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    errorCallback(e);
                });
        };
    }

    const bot = {
        id: params['botid'] || 'botid',
        name: params['botname'] || 'botname'
    };

    window.botchatDebug = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === 'true';

    var speechOptions;
    if (Modernizr.speechsynthesis) {
        speechOptions = {
            speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
                fetchCallback: function (authFetchEventId) { return getBingToken() },
                fetchOnExpiryCallback: function (authFetchEventId) { getBingToken() }
            }),
            speechSynthesizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()
        };
    }
    else if (Modernizr.getusermedia) {
        speechOptions = {
            speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({
                fetchCallback: function (authFetchEventId) { return getBingToken() },
                fetchOnExpiryCallback: function (authFetchEventId) { getBingToken() }
            }),
            speechSynthesizer: null
        };
    }
    else {
        speechOptions = null;
    }


    // for bot

    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        domain: params['domain'],
        //token: document.getElementById("directLineToken").value,
        secret: 'Secret',
        webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
    });


        BotChat.App({
            sendTyping: true,
            locale: params['locale'],
            resize: 'detect',
            speechOptions: speechOptions,
            user: { id:'ID' name: "You" },
            bot: { id: 'Vera', name: "Vera" },
            botConnection: botConnection
        }, document.getElementById('BotChatElement'));


    function getBingToken() {
        // Normally this token fetch is done from your secured backend to avoid exposing the API key and this call
        // would be to your backend, or to retrieve a token that was served as part of the original page.
        return fetch(
            'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'Key'
                },
                method: 'POST'
            }
            //).then(res => res.text());
        ).then(function (res) { return res.text() });
    }
```

aNY BODY Know how to do this  ?

Thank in advance .

Comment: The web chat control has not fully caught up to the transition from Bing Speech to Cognitive Services Speech.  More information can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1217

Comment: Cognitive Services Speech keys now work with the latest version of WebChat: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1336